# Unable to capture unhandled errors on Ionic 1 apps

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, error-handling, dom-events

We are trying to setup a top level global unhadled error detector on our hybrid Ionic 1 app. Following [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror#window.addEventListener('error')), we have subscribed to `window.addEventListener` in order to do so, but it's capturing almost nothing. Then, we started using [Angular's $exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24exceptionHandler) and it solves the issue partially, but it's still missing the HTTP and script errors. Details:

- resource errors (image download errors, script parse errors) are not being handled by `window.addEventListener` nor by Angular's $exceptionHandler
- errors thrown by controller loading, ionic events like `beforeEnter`, ionic methods called from the UI through template events bindings, ajax calls... none of them are handled by `window.addEventListener` - Angular's $exceptionHandler does handle them
- Surprisingly, all code scheduled with a `setTimeout` from all those places *is* properly handled by `window.addEventListener`

Next files demonstrates all what has been assured:

```
// app.js

angular.module("starter", [dependencies]).config(function () {
    window.addEventListener("error", function (event) {
        console.error("Error caught", event);
    });
});
```

.

```
// controllers.js

angular.module('starter.controllers', [dependencies]).controller("HomeCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    var nullVariable = null;
    var assignmentTarget;

    $scope.testClick = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            assignmentTarget = nullVariable.testClickTimeout; // handled
        }, 0);

        assignmentTarget = nullVariable.testClick; // unhandled
    };

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            assignmentTarget = nullVariable.homeCtrlBeforeEnterTimeout; // handled
        }, 0);

        assignmentTarget = nullVariable.homeCtrlBeforeEnter; // unhandled
    });

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        responseType: "json",
        url: "comeurl"
    }).then(function (response) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            assignmentTarget = nullVariable.ajaxResponseTimeout; // handled
        }, 0);

        assignmentTarget = nullVariable.ajaxResponse; // unhandled
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        assignmentTarget = nullVariable.homeCtrlTimeout; // handled
    }, 0);

    assignmentTarget = nullVariable.homeCtrl; // unhandled

});
```

Comment: Are you looking for [$exceptionHandler](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler)? angularjs handles there "unhandled js errors" so they're not unhandled anymore

Comment: @barbsan thank you, it helped handle the JS errors, but not the HTTP errors and script errors, which is the reason for wanting to use the global error handler

Comment: Have you tried rethrowing there angularJS errors and use your global error handler?

Comment: maybe I am not explaining right. The HTTP errors launch *no* error handler and *no* Angular handler